# What other documents can you write in order to plan out your scripts?

Tags: creative-writing, script

https://blog.prepscholar.com/what-is-plot-definition

I am writing a script for a TV show and basically I have the plot all figured out and the subsections of the document where I detail out the plot can be summarized as:

1. Exposition/introduction
2. Rising action
3. Climax/turning point
4. Falling action
5. Resolution/denouement

Now, it's nice to have to plot detailed out, but can I also fill out other documents to plan it out better? Writing the script for each episode after writing out the plot is still difficult, because each episode may have some fillers and details not already laid out in the document where I laid out the plot, so I am wondering if there are other documents that can help me transition from plot to the actual collections of scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the [Blake Snyder Beat Sheet](http://varieurfilmstudies.weebly.com/uploads/2/2/5/7/2257880/blakesnyderbeatsheet-explained.pdf); it breaks down a movie script into 15 parts.

Noam Kroll further divides this into his [40 Beat Sheet](https://noamkroll.com/this-simple-beat-sheet-technique-will-help-you-finish-your-feature-screenplay-in-record-time/) idea, for a feature film (110 to 120 pages).

I am unaware of a beat sheet template for a TV Series, but you can adapt the same ideas, particularly the beats.

A "beat" is an important moment in your story; it may be a single scene, or a few strongly linked scenes that result in a revelation to the viewer.

You can actually break this down further to a scene-by-scene outline; typically scenes are just a page or two long (a minute or two of screen time).

For a series, you have the added constraint that each episode both reveal something new AND tease something after; they each need those same elements of Exposition ("Previously On Thirty Swans..."), Rising action, A climax, Then not "resolution" but a new problem or discovery, a tease to watch the next episode.

Unless you are writing mostly standalone episodes, a la Star Trek or a Mystery series; where most episodes could be played in almost any order once the original characters were developed. These are usually character-based, a special character or crew we watch solve a lot of standalone problems. Cop shows, Doctor shows, Lawyer shows, a lot of comedies like Cheers, The Office, etc.

For a more coherent series with its own full arc; you need each episode to have five acts. I recommend this by Ken Miyamoto; [How to Structure and Format Your Television Scripts](https://thescriptlab.com/features/screenwriting-101/8930-how-to-structure-and-format-your-television-scripts/); where he explains the Five Acts for an episode.

You can adapt Noam Kroll's detailed beat sheets to both the overall series arc, and then the individual Five Acts of each episode.

I would also add Blake Snyder's "+/-" and "><" to every scene; these stand for Emotional Change, and Conflict.

"+/-" is followed by one line telling what has emotionally changed in this scene for one or more characters, from good to bad or bad to good. Mary is despondent, her plan failed, but reviewing the tape discovers a new clue, and her spirits pick up.

"><" is a line detailing the Conflict that drives this scene. Mary knows Jack is lying, but Jack can't tell the truth without endangering her.

Forcing yourself to write these one-liners will help you weed out weak scenes; as a rule of thumb every scene should change a character in some way, and should have some sort of conflict, even if that is mild disagreement. Even exposition, this should never be a neutral dump of information; part of the creativity challenge in writing is to deliver exposition in a way that entertains, and that means conflict, even if it is friendly conflict.

Hope those links help.

Comment: I'll pick this as the answer, but if something better comes up, I might change.